# WP_Query code outputs the PHP in the HTML instead of results

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a page that is supposed to display 3 of the latest posts in a certain category. The PHP code to make it work is below

```
<section id="projects">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <h2><span class="w200">Latest </span><span class="w600 green">Roofing Projects</span></h2>
    <p class="text-center pad_bottom">Click to view latest project</p>

      <?php //latest projects loop
      $latestProj = new WP_Query('cat=3&posts_per_page=3');

        if ($latestProj->have_posts()) :

          while ($latestProj->have_posts()) : $latestProj->the_post(); ?>


      <div class="col-lg-4">
        <?php
          if (has_post_thumbnail()) {
            the_post_thumbnail('square-thumbnail'); ?>
        <p class="proj_title"><?php the_title(); ?></p>
        <p><?php the_title(); ?></p>
      </div>

      <?php endwhile;

        else :

      endif;
    wp_reset_postdata();

    ?>

    </div>
      <p class="pad_top text-center"><a role="button" href="#" class="westbtn btn btn-lg">View Project Gallery »</a></p>
  </div>
</section>
```

Instead of results my page shows the following

http://www.roof.zenwebcreative.com.au/test/

I am just a beginner with PHP and I got the code from various sources which all show the same way for writing the code. I would appreciate any help in this matter. Thanks

Comment: How did you include that code?

Comment: If you are trying to input PHP code in your post directly this wont be possible.. In that case the PHP tag is escaped ..

Comment: You sure it's a .php page instead of a .html page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out from your comments I was including it it in the wrong place. Firstly I should have mentioned I was working on Wordpress. I was including that code within a page through wp-admin. I should be including that in the template page instead. It works now.